# How to solve Zoho Project API General error 6500?

Tags: php, rest, post, yii2, zoho

I am working on Zoho Projects API. I have got an API key when sending an HTTP post. While sending the post request I am getting an error.

**API CALL CODE**

```
$request_url ='https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/[PORTALID]/projects/'.$proj_id.'/bugs/?';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$request_parameters = array(
'authtoken' => 'token',
'title' =>'Meter No '.$msn.'_'.$issue_name,
'assignee'=>$assigne_name,
'flag'=>'Internal',
'classification_id'=> $class_id,
'module_id'=>$module_id,
'severity_id'=>$sevr_id,
'CHAR2'=>$ref_no,
'LONG1'=>$msn,

 );

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($request_parameters));

 /* Here you can set the Response Content Type */
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
 /* Let's give the Request Url to Curl */
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
 /*
 Yes we want to get the Response Header
 (it will be mixed with the response body but we'll separate that after)
 */
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
 /* Allows Curl to connect to an API server through HTTPS */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
/* Let's get the Response ! */
$response = curl_exec($ch);
/* We need to get Curl infos for the http_code */
$response_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
/* Don't forget to close Curl */
curl_close($ch);
/* Here we get the Response Body */
$response_body = substr($response, $response_info['header_size']);
// Response HTTP Status Code
echo "Response HTTP Status Code : ";
echo $response_info['http_code'];
echo "\n";
// Response Body
echo "Response Body : ";
echo $response_body;
```

The response I am getting is

```
Response HTTP Status Code : 400
Response Body : {"error":{"code":6500,"message":"General Error"}}
```

A solution is mentioned [here](https://help.zoho.com/portal/community/topic/zoho-project-api-general-error-6500). But it's not helping me anymore.

Zoho its self is providing a [PHP Example](https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/examples.html) that I am using.

**Update 1**

Ok, I added `$request_url .= '?' . http_build_query($request_parameters);` after `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($request_parameters));`
and then again checked the response. The URL is below

```
https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/[PORTALID]/projects/[PROJECTID]/bugs/?authtoken=key&title=Meter+No+002999000368_Site+Comm+Issue&assignee=Laar+Circle&flag=Internal&classification_id=1139168000000297069&module_id=1139168000000019372&severity_id=1139168000000007003&CHAR1=farhan_javaid&CHAR2=20372210038297U&LONG1=002999000368
```

There is `+` Sign in between the spaces which is causing a problem. There should be empty spaces in between the words. Like `Meter+No+002999000368_Site+Comm+Issue` should be `Meter No 002999000368_Site Comm Issue`.

How to get rid of this error. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: is this the actual code from your development environment that you are using ? or not

Comment: yes it is the actual code

Comment: updated the answer see if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the above code is what you exactly used then you might have to change the `[PORTALID]` in the `$request_url` to the actual portal id that you have assigned,

```
$request_url ='https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/[PORTALID]/projects/'.$proj_id.'/bugs/?';
```

see [**`here`**](https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/portals-api.html) how to get the `portal_id`.

**EDIT**

As you are having the problem due to the encoding of the spaces into `+` which is due to the encoding used by [**`http_build_query()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php), you can use `urlencode()` for the title inside the `$request_parameters` so that it uses `%20` instead of `+` although the rules say that

**`You should have %20 before the ? and + after.`**

otherwise, you might have to remove the spaces from the `'title' =>urlencode('Meter No '.$msn.'_'.$issue_name),`  if the API does not allow you anyhow

```
$request_parameters = array(
'authtoken' => 'token',
'title' =>urlencode('Meter No '.$msn.'_'.$issue_name),
'assignee'=>$assigne_name,
'flag'=>'Internal',
'classification_id'=> $class_id,
'module_id'=>$module_id,
'severity_id'=>$sevr_id,
'CHAR2'=>$ref_no,
'LONG1'=>$msn,

 );
```

Comment: what do you mean by PORTAL_ID is correct ? you need to replace the placeholder `[PORTALID]` with the actual `portal_id` @MrFaisal

Comment: Yes that's what I am saying. I am placing the portal ID value in actual. Just for hiding here I have used the name

Comment: **USTAD** pehle hi maan leta meri baat, glad it worked :) @MrFaisal

Comment: sure give me some time @MrFaisal