# Zoho Projects API Timesheet - General Error 6500 - Adding time entry

Tags: php, rest, post, yii2, zoho

Integration: Active Collab - Zoho Projects
I'm trying to create a new Time entry under a task in Zoho Projects, using the API.

I've already synced up tasks and projects. But I'm having a hard time creating a time entry.
I've tried with php and with postman. On both ends I get the same error:

```
Response HTTP Status Code : 400
{"error":{"code":6500,"message":"General Error"}}
```

Here's my request:

```
$request_parameters = array(
                'authtoken'   => 'APITOKEN',
                'date'        => '02-20-2018',
                'bill_status' => 'Billable',
                'hours'       => '02:22'
);
```

These are being passed as URL parameters.

If I change any of the parameters the error code changes.
I'm using the example provided in the Zoho Project [documentation page](https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/log-time.html#alink2):
Not sure what's up.

Here's the request URL:

```
https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/hidden_portal_id/projects/1167980000000355033/tasks/1167980000000355033/logs/?authtoken=hidden_api_token&date=02-20-2018&bill_status=Billable&hours=02%3A22
```

[I've found a similar thread but could not figure it out based on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48881818/how-to-solve-zoho-project-api-general-error-6500)

Thanks.
Here's the full code:

```
/* Set the Request Url (without Parameters) here */
$request_url = 'https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/hidden_portal_id/projects/'.$endpoint;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$request_parameters = array(
        'authtoken'   => 'hidden_api_key',
        'date'        => '02-20-2018',
        'bill_status' => 'Billable',
        'hours'       => '02:22'
    );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($request_parameters));

//I've added this line because I've found a similar error 6500 thread see the link above
$request_url .=  '?'. http_build_query($request_parameters);

/* Here you can set the Response Content Type */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));

/* Let's give the Request Url to Curl */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);

/* Allows Curl to connect to an API server through HTTPS */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
d($request_parameters,$request_url);

/* Let's get the Response ! */
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$response_info = curl_getinfo($ch);

/* Don't forget to close Curl */
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: can you check by removing `date` and `hours` one by one from the `$request_parameters` if they are the one causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried that but then it throws "Input Parameter Missing". I've sent a support request to Zoho and they said the developers will fix it. So it must be an internal issue with the API.
Anybody else encountering the same error?
Thanks!

Comment: hmm that must be it then , as mostly having spaces decoded to `+` in the parameter values, causes this exception too, which isn't in your case

Comment: Thanks for your time dough! I will post here the solution to the problem as soon as Zoho Dev team comes back with updates. Have a good one.

Comment: @Istvan did you get the any response from ZOHO developers?? I'm facing the same issue here